# Hibernate mappedBy

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Please tell me why I incorrectly linked the tables. 
PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:oracle:thin:@ARS-PS-DEV:1521:ars]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Initial SessionFactory failedorg.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.ecls.ARSTools.DAO.CertificateField.сertificate in com.ecls.ARSTools.DAO.Certificate.certificateFields
    at com.ecls.ARSTools.Tools.HibernateSessionFactory.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:21)
    at com.ecls.ARSTools.Tools.HibernateSessionFactory.(HibernateSessionFactory.java:10)
    at com.ecls.ARSTools.Tools.ImplARS.(ImplARS.java:14)
    at ecls.temp.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:16)

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name= "CERTIFICATE")
    public class Certificate implements IAvailableID{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cert_generator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="cert_generator", sequenceName = "SWS_CERTIFICATE_ID", allocationSize=1)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name= "NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length=50)
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(targetEntity=CertificateField.class, mappedBy = "сertificate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<CertificateField> certificateFields=new ArrayList<CertificateField>();

        public Certificate() {
            super();
        }

        public Certificate(String name, List<CertificateField> certificateFields) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.certificateFields = certificateFields;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<CertificateField> getCertificateFields() {
            return certificateFields;
        }

        public void setCertificateFields(List<CertificateField> certificateFields) {
            this.certificateFields = certificateFields;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String res;
            res="-------------------\n";
            res+="Certificate [id=" + id + ", name=" + name+"]\n";
            for(CertificateField item:certificateFields){
                res+=item.toString()+"\n";
            }   
            return res;
        }   
    }


@Entity
@Table(name= "CERTIFICATE_FIELD")
public class CertificateField implements IAvailableID{
    @Id
    @Column(name= "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "NAME", nullable = false, length=50)
    private String name;    

    @Column(name= "VALUE", nullable = false, length=50)
    private String value;   

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Certificate.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CERTIFICATE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable = false)
    private Certificate certificate;    

    public CertificateField(){
        super();
    }

    public CertificateField(String name, String value, Certificate certificate) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.certificate = certificate;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public Certificate getCertificate() {
        return certificate;
    }

    public void setCertificate(Certificate certificate) {
        this.certificate = certificate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "certificate field [id=" + getId() + ", name=" + getName()+ ", value=" + getValue()+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: try without the "targetEntity" attribute? since any decent JPA provider should be capable of getting the related type via generics

Comment: The result is the same. I already tried this ((

Comment: both classes listed in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Эти классы введены в hibernate.cfg.hml. Если я извлекаю List <CertificateField> certificateFields из сертификата, то я получаю данные из таблицы базы данных. <mapping class="com.ecls.ARSTools.DAO.Certificate"/>
  <mapping class="com.ecls.ARSTools.DAO.CertificateField"/>

Comment: I'm confused by the following entry in the console: PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop

Answer (score 0):

I decided. The problem was in the meaning of update hbm2ddl. Fixed on 
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">auto</property>`